# Salesforce to android Native App connetivity Using Access Token

Tags: connected-apps, android

Unable to get access token. here my code given below

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String query = "SELECT Name, Idfrom Account";
private static final String clientId = "";
private static final String clientSecret = "";
private static final String redirectUri = "";
private static final String environment = "http://login.salesforce.com";
private static String tokenUrl = null;
private static final String username = "";
private static final String password = "";
private static String accessToken = null;
private static String instanceUrl = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    // Creating HTTP client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    tokenUrl = environment + "/services/oauth2/token";

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(tokenUrl);

    // Building post parameters
    // key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", clientId));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", clientSecret));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", redirectUri));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // Url Encoding the POST parameters
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        // writing response to log
        Log.v("Http Response: >>>>>", "Http Response: >>>>>0000   "
                + response);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

}

in response i'm getting org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@917d22c

Comment: You can use Salesforce REST api in your app to get salesforce data. Salesforce provides a REST api and you can refer following link for more information.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/

Comment: yes, I have used Rest API and I get the Salesforce data. but my requirement is I am not wanted login screen. when the app is started it will first ask for credentials. there is any way without login I get salesforce data or through code login is possible.

Comment: Grab an access token using the connected app and use it to make rest calls. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm

Comment: I am getting error while request for token  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve access token for user: I also post my code

Comment: Thanks, ankit.sehgal i get salesforce records using access tokn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Access Salesforce records in Android Native App without login credentials, you first need to grab access token from salesforce.

To get access token you can follow this link.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm

After grabbing a token you need to make REST calls to get Salesforce Records.

package com.example.admin.myapplication;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
// The connection data
private static final String query = "SELECT Name, Id from Account";
private static final String clientId = "Your salesforce consumer Key";
private static final String clientSecret = "Secret Key";
// THis is meaningless in our context
private static final String redirectUri = "Redirect URI";
//private static final String environment = "https://harishgakhar40-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com";
private static final String environment = "https://login.salesforce.com";
private static String tokenUrl = null;
private static final String username = "salesforce Username";
private static final String password = "salesforce password + security token";
private static String accessToken = null;
private static String instanceUrl = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create list adapter
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
    ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list)).setAdapter(listAdapter);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    // Creating HTTP client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    tokenUrl = environment + "/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(tokenUrl);

    // Building post parameters
    // key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", "application/json"));
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONTokener tokener;
    String accessToken,instanceURL;
    JSONArray finalResult;
    // Making HTTP Request
    try {

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String json = reader.readLine();
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        accessToken = jObj.getString("access_token");
        instanceURL = jObj.getString("instance_url");
       getAccountData(accessToken, instanceURL);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.getMessage();

    }
}


public  void getAccountData(String access_token, String instance_url) {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String url = instance_url + "/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=";
    String soqlQuery = "Select Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState From Account ";

    try
    {
        url += URLEncoder.encode(soqlQuery, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){}

    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + access_token);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
        JSONArray records = object.getJSONArray("records");

        listAdapter.clear();
        for (int i=0;i<records.length();i++) {


            JSONObject record = (JSONObject) records.get(i);
            String accountName = record.getString("Name");
            Log.v("accountName---- ","accountName ---- "+accountName);
            listAdapter.add(accountName);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}